# [Unity3D]How to create an assetbundle of an image folders and then load these images as texture?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I'm new to Unity. Now I have an image folder which includes around 749 .jpg images. I want to create an assetbundle of this folder. In the game, I want to load these .jpg iamges one by one and set it as Texture2D.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find full guide on Unity Blog(how to make and load asset bundles) as it said:

> AssetBundles are files created in the Unity editor during edit-time,
>   which can be used later by a build of a project at run-time.
>   AssetBundles can contain asset files such as models, materials,
>   **textures** and scenes. AssetBundles cannot contain scripts.
>   ([Read This](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/assetbundles-and-assetbundle-manager))

Answer (score 0):

After downloading asset bundle either by WWW or WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload do this:

```
WWW www = new WWW(url);//download aaset
                AssetBundle assetBundle = www.assetBundle;
                AssetBundleRequest request = assetBundle.LoadAssetAsync<Image>("nameOfImage");
                Texture texture = request.asset as Textute;
```

put this code under IEnumerator and yeild return www;